# Session Expires, redirect to login screen

Tags: vb.net, web-applications

I have a login page where it changes the screen but still on the same page once the user is authenticated. Now I wanted the user to be redirected to the first screen(login screen) if there is inactivity of let's say 10 minutes or once the sessions expires. May I ask for help on how to implement this? Thank you!